# Using R - If columns A and B do not match, replace entries in columns C and D with 'NA'

Tags: r

I have 4 columns in a dataframe:

```
dd <- data.frame(
  A= c(102,101,100,107,55),
  B= c(102,101,30,77,55),
  C= c("cycle", "walk", "walk", "walk", "drive"),
  D= c("English", "French", "English", "English", "Japanese")
)
```

Using R, I wish to compare if entries in columns A and B matches. If entries in A and B do not match, then I wish to replace their corresponding entries in column C and D with 'NA'.

```
desired <- data.frame(
  A= c(102,101,100,107, 55),
  B= c(102,101,30,77, 55),
  C= c("cycle", "walk", NA, NA, "drive"),
  D= c("English", "French", NA, NA, "Japanese")
)
```

Can anyone advise? The qn is not  new but the proposed solutions are usually in Excel. I hope to do this in R. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` approach:

Across column C and column D, if A is not equal to B, set `NA`, if they are equal, use their original values.

**UPDATE: since your column A and B are factors of different levels, you might want to change them into character first, do the operation, then change them back to factor.**

```
library(dplyr)

dd %>% mutate(across(A:B, ~as.character(.x)), 
              across(C:D, ~ ifelse(A != B, NA, as.character(.x))), 
              across(A:B, ~as.factor(.x)))

   A   B     C        D
1 102 102 cycle  English
2 101 101  walk   French
3 100  30  <NA>     <NA>
4 107  77  <NA>     <NA>
5  55  55 drive Japanese
```

Comment: Thanks so much. However, I got this error: `<error/dplyr:::mutate_error>
Problem with mutate() input ..1. i ..1 = across(...). x level sets of factors are different`. Must both factors (A and B) have the same number of levels?

Comment: Yes, or you can change them to character first, and change them back later. See if my edited answer helps.

Comment: Thank you! It works, except that it now changes C and D to integers as well. I have no idea why it changes C and D to integers (1,2,3,..) when they were factors (cycle, walk, etc.) Could it be because of `.x`?

Comment: Next time when you ask on SO, it's better to include `dput()` of your dataframe, so that we will know your column type exactly. Use `as.character(.x)` to avoid the problem, see my updated answer :)

Comment: Thank you so much! This works perfectly. Ok, I'll learn how to use `dput()`!

Answer (score 0):

A simple option

```
df[df$A!=df$B,c("C","D")]=NA
```

if A and B are factors you could try

```
df[as.character(df$A)!=as.character(df$B),c("C","D")]=NA
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! However, I faced this error: `Error in Ops.factor(df$A, df$B) : level sets of factors are different`. (Indeed my df$A has fewer levels than df$B, due to its nature.) Is there a way to go about this, even with different level sets of factors?

Comment: After changing A and B to characters (instead of factors), it works... but I think the code should be: `df[df$A!=df$B,c("C","D")]=NA`. Thanks!